# lighttpd, mod_rewrite, web.py

Tags: python, lighttpd, web.py

I've a small issue with lighttpd and web.py. It runs perfectly fine on Apache2 but there's a small issue on lighttpd.

Here's my lighttpd config for web.py

```
  fastcgi.server = ("/code.py" =>
    ((
      "socket" => "/tmp/fcgi.socket",
      "bin-path" => "/home/ivan/www/code.py",
      "max-procs" => 1,
      "check-local" => "disable",
    ))
  )

  url.rewrite-once = (
     "^/favicon.ico$" => "/static/favicon.ico",
     "^/static/(.*)$" => "/static/$1",
     "^/(.*)$" => "/code.py/$1"
   )
```

and a sample web.py to demonstrate how I've defined to URLs.

```
urls = (
  '/page', 'Page',
  '/', 'Index',
)

class Index(object):
  def GET(self):
    raise web.seeother('/page')
```

The problem occurs when the browser is redirected to `example.org/page` URL. Apache2 redirects to `example.org/page` but lighttpd redirects to `example.org/code.py/page`. How can I fix this small issue? I've found a solution, so if I write `raise web.seeother(web.ctx.homedomain+'/page')` everything is fine but I'd like to know if it can be solved in lighttpd config file instead of touching the web.py code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Before spawning your script with fastcgi just set

```
export REAL_SCRIPT_NAME=""
```

this should work.

Comment: What does REAL_SCRIPT_NAME="" do?  Didn't find mention of it in the lighttpd doc.  Thanks.

Comment: some info on REAL_SCRIPT_NAME: https://groups.google.com/g/webpy/c/54TR8U5NZ9c, https://groups.google.com/g/webpy/c/iglqpXU4lfs