# web.py and lighttpd error: Connection refused, child exited: 1

Tags: python, webserver, lighttpd, web.py

I'm running web.py with lighttpd with very similar config to what's suggested on [the website](https://webpy.org/cookbook/fastcgi-lighttpd). When I run it with `/etc/init.d/lighttpd start` I get these errors in the logs:

```
2022-11-07 21:30:59: (gw_backend.c.528) connect /tmp/fastcgi.socket-0: Connection refused
2022-11-07 21:30:59: (gw_backend.c.371) child exited: 1 unix:/tmp/fastcgi.socket-0
2022-11-07 21:30:59: (gw_backend.c.512) new proc, socket: 0 /tmp/fastcgi.socket-0
2022-11-07 21:30:59: (gw_backend.c.528) connect /tmp/fastcgi.socket-0: Connection refused
2022-11-07 21:30:59: (gw_backend.c.371) child exited: 1 unix:/tmp/fastcgi.socket-0
```

It works when I test it with `lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`.

My python file starts with `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and is executable.

Answer (score 0):

The program was failing because environment variables weren't being passed. I don't love the current resolution, and I plan on coming back to it later. For now, I set environment variables in `lighttpd.conf`. In `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` (good links for reference [webpy.org](https://webpy.org/cookbook/fastcgi-lighttpd) [ongspxm.gitlab.io](https://ongspxm.gitlab.io/blog/2014/07/running-webpy-projects-with-lighttpd-fastcgi/)):

```
fastcgi.server = (
    "/app.py" => (
        "webpy" => (
            "socket" => "/tmp/fastcgi.socket",
            "min-procs" => 1,
            "bin-path" => "PATH_TO_CODE/app.py",
            "bin-environment" => (
                "REAL_SCRIPT_NAME" => "",
                "ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_A" => "example_a",
                "ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_B" => "example_b"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

To debug this I made a simple web.py app (mostly from [the homepage](https://webpy.org)) and outputted the environment variables. It might help you debug:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.10

import web
import os
urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'hello'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name:
            name = 'World'
        return str(os.environ)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

More info on REAL_SCRIPT_NAME: [lighttpd, mod_rewrite, web.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802218/lighttpd-mod-rewrite-web-py#comment131265671_7391258)

`/etc/init.d/lighttpd status` was helpful for figuring out the issue.

<s>Changing `#!/usr/bin/env python3` to `#!/usr/bin/env python3.10` fixed it. Unfortunately I'm not sure why.</s>